# How to click on "Save" button in IE software download bar using JNA

Tags: java, windows, internet-explorer, jna

I have a IE's download bar:
[image: IE download bar]

I need to find a way to click on one of those buttons or get location of either of "Run", "Save" or "Cancel"
I am using Java and JNA, so far code looks like this:

```
import com.sun.jna.Native;
import com.sun.jna.Pointer;
import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinDef.HWND;
import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinUser.WNDENUMPROC;
import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.User32;

public class IEOperations {

    private static HWND wind;
    private static String title;

    public static HWND findWind(final String name) {
        final User32 user32 = User32.INSTANCE;
        title=null;
        wind = null;
        user32.EnumWindows(new WNDENUMPROC() {
            public boolean callback(HWND hWnd, Pointer arg1) {
                char[] windowText = new char[512];
                user32.GetWindowText(hWnd, windowText, 512);
                String wText = Native.toString(windowText);
                if (wText.contains(name)) {
                    title = wText;
                    wind = hWnd;
                    return false;
                }
                return true;
            }
        }, null);
        return wind;
    }

    public static String activate(String app) {
        User32 user32 = User32.INSTANCE;
        HWND hWnd = findWind(app);
        user32.ShowWindow(hWnd, User32.SW_SHOWMAXIMIZED);
        user32.SetForegroundWindow(hWnd);
        return title;
    }

    public static String getTitle(String app) {
        findWind(app);
        return title;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(activate("GitHub Desktop")); //Just test to show that code finds and activates window that I need.
        //TODO: Get Button objects and move cursor to those buttons and click... OR just click on "Save" button...
    }
}
```

The code above finds a window by partial title and activates it. How can I click get "Save" object and click on it?

Comment: GitHub have an app for that.

Comment: what is the name of the app?

Comment: Git shell - Git hub is discontinuing support for IE. To manage your gits use Git shell.

Comment: It is not about github,  I need to find the way of clicking on the buttons, the githubis just an example.

Comment: your screen shot shows you are using Edge, not IE. You can use Selenium web driver to automate Edge (and click buttons).  For IE you can use VBscript, vba, powershell or .net WBC to automate it.

Comment: Thanks for reply Rob, I know Selenium can click around, it can't click on buttons of Browser's download bar. Of course I can use VBS or powershell to send Alt+S key for quick save. but I really need to click on those buttons using JNA, there are multiple reasons and restrictions in the project.